# Message insufficient_quota api GTP openAi

Tags: openai-api, quota

I'm having some problems integrating the GPT openAi API into an application I'm developing.

I recently registered on the platform with a new email and, when generating the API key, I associated a phone number that I am sure is not linked to any account (since it is my mother's and she does not use these tools) . However, at that time, the platform told me that they cannot give me the free credits they offer to new accounts due to this phone number reason.

Due to this, when trying to consume the API it responds with a message that says that I have exceeded the quota, I suppose because of what was previously reported.

I am sure the account is new and there is an available balance
[Usage profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFeK2.png)
[API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km5vg.png)

I already tried to contact support and they don't give me a solution, it seems like an automatic response.

I tried using different models, without getting a different response